# is it possible to draw a big number of simple geometric figures in HTML5.canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this awesome piece of code.

The idea, as you can imagine,is to draw a grid of rectangles. I want a big grid, let's say 100 X 100 or more.

However, when i run the awesome piece of code for the desired size (100X 100), my browser crashes.

How can i achieve that?

*** please note: when i say 100X100 i mean the final number of rectangles (10k) not the size of the canvas.**

thank u

```
function init() {        
    var cnv = get('cnv');
    var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
    var ancho = 12; // ancho means width
    var alto = 12;  // alto means height
    ctx.fillStyle = randomRGB();

    for (var i = 0; i < cnv.width; i+= ancho) {
        for (var j = 0; j < cnv.height; j+= alto) {
            //dibujar means to draw, rectangulo means rectangle
            dibujarRectangulo(i+ 1, j+1, ancho, alto, ctx); 
        }
    }
}

function dibujarRectangulo(x, y, ancho, alto, ctx) {
    ctx.rect(x, y, ancho, alto);      
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Comment: Dunno if it's relevant, but have you seen [Pixi.js bunnymark](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/bunnymark_v3/)?

Comment: @paddy i think i love you. thanks

Comment: @paddy however i wonder, can one resort to plain html5 to draw massive ammounts of geometries or is it mandatory to use a 3rd party lib?

Comment: The lib can't do anything that you can't also do yourself; it just saves you work of doing it (and mistakes you are likely to commit). In this case, pixi.js is using hardware acceleration, AFAIK.

Comment: It is easy to draw 10K rectangles on the 2D canvas in real-time but the problem is you will have very limited control of those rectangles. Its not so much about how many rectangles you want but how much control and what each can do. What do you want each rectangle to do?

Comment: @Blindman67 your comment puzzles me. how do you get 10000 rectangles in a canvas? mind to share the code? and, answering your question, initially i want them to stand still, as smiling trophy wives, but, of course, once you have something in your canvas you want it to move. So, level 2, would be the ability to randomly asign velocity, on x and y, to every rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**16,384 boxes on the wall**

As I said in the comment its easy to draw a lot of boxes, it is not easy to have them all behave uniquely. Anyways using render to self to duplicate boxes exponential there are 128 * 128 boxes so that's 16K, one more iteration and it would be 64K boxes.

Its a cheat, I could have just drawn random pixels and called each pixel a box.

Using canvas you will get upto 4000 sprites per frame on a top end machine using FireFox with each sprite having a location, center point, rotation, x and y scale, and an alpha value. But that is the machine going flat out.

Using WebGL you can get much higher but the code complexity goes up.

I use a general rule of thumb, if a canva 2D project has more than 1000 sprites then it is in need of redesign.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

/** CreateImage.js begin **/
var createImage = function (w, h) {
    var image = document.createElement("canvas");
    image.width = w;
    image.height = h;
    image.ctx = image.getContext("2d");
    return image;
}
/** CreateImage.js end **/
/** FrameUpdate.js begin **/
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2;
var ch = h / 2;
var boxSize = 10;
var boxSizeH = 5;
var timeDiv = 1.2;
var bBSize = boxSize * 128; // back buffer ssize
var buff = createImage(bBSize, bBSize);
var rec = createImage(boxSize, boxSize);
var drawRec = function (ctx, time) {
    var size, x, y;
    size = (Math.sin(time / 200) + 1) * boxSizeH;
    ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + Math.floor((Math.sin(time / 500) + 1) * 180) + ",100%,50%)";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, boxSize, boxSize);
    x = Math.cos(time / 400);
    y = Math.sin(time / 400);
    ctx.setTransform(x, y, -y, x, boxSizeH, boxSizeH)
    ctx.fillRect(-boxSizeH + size, -boxSizeH + size, boxSize - 2 * size, boxSize - 2 * size);
    ctx.strokeRect(-boxSizeH + size, -boxSizeH + size, boxSize - 2 * size, boxSize - 2 * size);
}
function update(time) {
    var fw, fh, px, py, i;
    time /= 7;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    drawRec(rec.ctx, time);
    time /= timeDiv;
    buff.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, bBSize, bBSize)
    buff.ctx.drawImage(rec, 0, 0);
    buff.ctx.drawImage(rec, boxSize, 0);

    fw = boxSize + boxSize; // curent copy area width
    fh = boxSize; // curent copy area height
    px = 0; // current copy to x pos
    py = boxSize; // current copy to y pos
    buff.ctx.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, fw, fh, px, py, fw, fh); // make square
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        drawRec(rec.ctx, time);
        time /= timeDiv;
        buff.ctx.drawImage(rec, 0, 0);
        fh += fh; // double size across
        px = fw;
        py = 0;
        buff.ctx.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, fw, fh, px, py, fw, fh); // make rec
        drawRec(rec.ctx, time);
        time /= timeDiv;
        buff.ctx.drawImage(rec, 0, 0);
        fw += fw; // double size down
        px = 0;
        py = fh;
        buff.ctx.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, fw, fh, px, py, fw, fh);
    }
    // draw the boxes onto the canvas,
    ctx.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, 1024, 1024);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();
```

```css
.canv {
  width:1024px;
  height:1024px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" class = "canv" width=1024 height=1024></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you very much. your animation is very trippy :)

Answer (score 2):

The dibujarRectanglo() function calls rect() function which adds a closed rectanglar subpath to the current path. Then calls fill() function to fill the current path. Then calls closePath() function to close the subpath, which does nothing since the subpath is already closed.

In other words, the first dibujarRectanglo() function call is painting a path that contains 1 rectangle subpath. The second call is painting a path that contains 2 rectangle subpaths. The third call is painting a path that contains 3 rectangle subpaths. And so on. If the loop calls dibujarRectanglo() function 10000 times then a total of 1+2+3+...+10000 = 50005000 (i.e. over 50 million) rectangle subpaths will be painted.

The dibujarRectangle() function should be starting a new path each time. For example...

```
function dibujarRectangulo(x, y, ancho, alto, ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(x, y, ancho, alto);      
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Then 10000 calls will only paint 10000 rectangle subpaths which is a lot faster that painting 50 million rectangle subpaths.

Comment: Thanks man, i forgot write down the  begin path thing. Your explanation, however, is very useful.